# How to export the exact values of the datagridview into excel VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I have a datagridview filled with values from an imported excel file. I change the headertext in the datagridview into another value and reorder them, and then export them again into an excel file. What's happening is I get the values that are changed but not the order (the order is still the order of the imported excel file). How can I import the values and the order of my datagridview? Refer to the code below:

```
'Code for Import
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Me.TextBox1.Text = path.ToString

    Try
        Me.dgvFile.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        Me.dgvFile.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("File successfully imported")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
End Sub

'Code for Convert
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=NewPass;database=converter"
    Dim MysqlReader As MySqlDataReader

    'Convert for Headers
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim MysqlQuery As String
    MysqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM headers"
    MysqlComm = New MySqlCommand(MysqlQuery, MysqlConn)
    MysqlReader = MysqlComm.ExecuteReader

    Dim y = 0
    Dim arrayContain As New List(Of String)
    Dim arrayRemove As New List(Of String)
    'Dim colIndex

    While MysqlReader.Read
        Dim header = MysqlReader.GetString("Header")
        Dim convert = MysqlReader.GetString("Convert")
        Dim strHeader = System.Convert.ToString(header)
        Dim strConvert = System.Convert.ToString(convert)
        Dim x = 0

        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgvFile.Columns
            If column.HeaderText = strHeader Then
                column.HeaderText = strConvert
                dgvFile.Columns(x).DisplayIndex = y
                y = y + 1
                arrayContain.Add(column.HeaderText)
            Else
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next
    End While

    For Each remove As DataGridViewColumn In dgvFile.Columns
        If arrayContain.Contains(remove.HeaderText) = False Then
            arrayRemove.Add(remove.HeaderText)
        End If
    Next

    For count As Integer = 0 To arrayRemove.Count - 1
        dgvFile.Columns.Remove(arrayRemove(count))
    Next

    MysqlComm.Dispose()
    MysqlReader.Close()
    MysqlConn.Close()

'Code for Export
Private Sub btnExport_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim sPath As String = String.Empty
    Dim dlgSave As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    dlgSave.DefaultExt = "xlsx"
    dlgSave.Filter = "Microsoft Excel|*.xlsx"

    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


        For i = 0 To dgvFile.RowCount - 1
            For j = 0 To dgvFile.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To dgvFile.Columns.Count
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvFile.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = "'" & dgvFile(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        Dim sFileName As String = dlgSave.FileName
        'Dim finalFilename As String = sFileName & ".xlsx"
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(sFileName)
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

        Dim res As MsgBoxResult
        res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
            Process.Start(sFileName)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

'releaseObject Code
Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This is the order of the IMPORTED excel into datagridview.
[image: columns1]
This is the order of the CONVERTED datagridview.
[image: columns2]
This is the order of the EXPORTED datagridview to excel.
[image: columns3]

You will notice that the IMPORTED and the EXPORTED have the same order. I want the EXPORTED to be the same order as the CONVERTED. I hope it's clear now and I hope someone can help me fix this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the values in the dt with the values you want during convert instead of changing the datagridview and make that dt with the converted value your dgv datasource. I think the export gets the values inside the dt and not the datagridview.

Comment: Your suggestion is late but yes, it does work like that. I figured it out and now it works perfectly. Still, thanks for the answer. :)